# How to build a graph of 500 points?

Tags: java, android, charts, mpandroidchart

I am using the MPAndroidChart library. I need to create a straight line of ~ 500 points. The problem is that I do not see the graph itself and the points. But if I manually add 5 points and build a graph on them, then everything will be displayed correctly.
I suspect that it is necessary to somehow solve the problem of displaying a large number of points, since they overlap each other.

```
    ArrayList<Entry> values = new ArrayList<>();
    //default: x1 = 200; x2 = 700
    for (int i = x1, index = 0, j = y; i < x2; ++i, ++index)
    {
        float waveLength = (float) calib_a * i +  (float) calib_b;
        int pixel = rotated.getPixel(i, j);
        float I = (Color.red(pixel) + Color.blue(pixel) + Color.green(pixel)) / 765.0f;
        values.add(new Entry(waveLength, I));
        Log.d("[SPECTRAl]", " WAVE:  " +waveLength + "  I: " + I);
    }

    LineDataSet lineValues = new LineDataSet(values, "");
    LineData line = new LineData(lineValues);
    chart.setData(line);
    chart.invalidate();
```

xml:

```
    <com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.LineChart
        android:id="@+id/chart"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Comment: Find answer on your other post and please don't post same question twice. 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/58195677/6740130

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MPAndroidChart - why line not showing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58173935/mpandroidchart-why-line-not-showing)